# command line SVN tagging

Tags: svn, command-line

I am fairly new to SVN tagging but the following looks strange, I was hoping for an explanation/validation that it is a bug and I can just workaround this.

if I call `svn copy --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username myName --password myPassword -m "My Comment" "https://subversion.somwhere.com/path/something SDK" "https://subversion.somwhere.com/path/something SDK Tags/1.14.67"`

once, I get a message that it was done successfully and the revision counter increases.

same for twice (which is odd,I would have expected an error here)

instead when I call the same line for the third time, I get an error which tells me "something SDK" already exists, which is also strange because I would have expected it to say "1.14.67" already exists

Comment: Path with spaces **must** be URL-encoded

Comment: If you are using TortoiseSVN, why is this question showing a command line? TortoiseSVN can *install* command line tools, but that would not be TortoiseSVN directly.

Comment: @LazyBadger , as long as you put the url in quotes the SVN client can handle it without URL encode (although I agree the proper way is probably with URL encode,but this does not effect the problem)

Comment: @crashmstr changed question to be SVN command lien related,thanks